# Python POST with urlencoded multidimensional dictionary

Tags: python, post, urlencode

I have many functions that successfully POST a urlencoded body using python.  However, I have a body that is a multidimensional dictionary.  Using this dictionary, I only get a 400 (bad request).  bodytmp (below) is an example of the body that works using Fiddler.  (The actual url and body can not be supplied.)  I have also included a recursive urlencode function that I found here and am using now but with no success.

Does anyone have experience with this type of POST request with a multidimensional dictionary for the urlencoded body?

Thank you.  ( I have abbreviated the code to make it more readable, but this is the gist. )

from httplib2 import Http
import httplib
import urllib

def postAgentRegister():

```
h = Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
headers={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

bodytmp={"Username": "username",
        "Password": "password",
        "AccountId": "accountid",
        "PublicKey": {
        "Value1a": "32ab45cd",
        "value1b": "10001"
                     },
        "snId": "SN1",
        "IpAddresses": {
        "Value2a": ["50.156.54.45"],
        "Value2b": "null"
                   }
        }

body=recursive_urlencode(bodytmp)

try:
    response,content=h.request('https://server/endpoint','POST',headers=headers,body=body)
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(testserver)
    conn.request('POST', endpoint, body, headers)
    r1 = conn.getresponse()
    status = r1.status
    reason = r1.reason

except httplib.HTTPException, e:
    status= e.code

print 'status is: ', status
```

def recursive_urlencode(d):
    def recursion(d, base=None):
        pairs = []

```
    for key, value in d.items():
        if hasattr(value, 'values'):
            pairs += recursion(value, key)
        else:
            new_pair = None
            if base:
                new_pair = "%s[%s]=%s" % (base, urllib.quote(unicode(key)), urllib.quote(unicode(value)))
            else:
                new_pair = "%s=%s" % (urllib.quote(unicode(key)), urllib.quote(unicode(value)))
            pairs.append(new_pair)
    return pairs

return '&'.join(recursion(d))
```

Comment: Have you tested this with a dictionary that has the intended structure but minimal content, in order to ensure that the problem isn't specific to the length / contents of your test data?

Comment: I'm using this code to test an existing API endpoint. IOW, there is not another endpoint that has similar structure but minimal content as you suggest.  However all other endpoints (without the nested levels in the json) work as expected. And the body above works when submitted via Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest that you serialize your body to JSON and de-serialize when your server receives it? This way you just have to do a url string encode rather than using your own recursive url encode.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean (being very new to python) but I'll do some looking around to see if I can find some examples to try.  Thank you.

Comment: This will help you get started with json http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Comment: Essentially you can convert or 'serialize' simple python dictionaries to a json string using json.dumps, and unserialize the string back to a python dictionary using json.loads.

this way, you can say urllib.quote(json.dumps(bodytmp)) in your request. And when you receive it in say a variable called 'data', call json.loads(data) to convert it back to a dictionary.

Comment: yes, I actually did use a json.dumps but on the recursively urlencoded  body (I didn't include any of my commented-out trial and error code in my example to retain clarity):         #response,content=h.request('https://'+testserver+endpoint,'POST',headers=headers,body=json.dumps(body))  but will try it on the non-urlencrypted bodytmp as you suggest.

Comment: nope... replacing the request with: response,content=h.request('https://'+testserver+endpoint,'POST',headers=header‌​s,body=json.dumps(bodytmp))  still returns 400... sigh

Comment: ok, that's the request, but what are you doing on the server side?

Comment: The server-side is API written in C#. I am testing the API (IOW, no influence.)  Can you be more specific and I will check with dev.